# How to check if boost::asio::io_service has started running?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

In the main thread, I'm creating 8 `std::thread`s in a loop.
All these threads will ultimately call `_ios.run() // _ios is per thread`.

In the Class definition:

```cpp
boost::asio::io_service                           _ios;
boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service::work>    _work;
std::thread                                       _thread;
```

Class constructor:

```cpp
{
      _work = boost::in_place(boost::ref(_ios));
      _thread = std::thread{[this] () {
              setup_a_few_stuffs();
              _ios.run();
          }
      };
}
```

In the main thread, I would like to post jobs to these `io_service`s but I want to be sure that all the threads have started running their `io_service`s i.e. all of them have called `_ios.run()` and are ready to process jobs.

Is there a way to query an `io_serivce` for its status?
If yes, then I could query all the threads' `io_service`s one by one to check if they are ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`stopped` member function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/stopped.html). According to the [Boost Asio Documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html):

> This function is used to determine whether an `io_context` object has been stopped, either through an explicit call to `stop()`, or due to running out of work. When an `io_context` object is stopped, calls to `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` will return immediately without invoking any handlers.

Using `!_ios.stopped()` you will know if `_ios` is still running.

Comment: `!_ios.stopped()` would evaluate to `true` if _ios.run() is yet to be called by the thread.

Comment: @void Yes, it would. Now I realized that I misunderstood your question. I thought that you wanted to wait for `_ios` to be done working to post new work, but now I see that you want to wait for `_ios.run()` to be called and only then post work. I see a problem with this approach, as if you call `run` before posting any work, the call will immediately return. Also, you don't have to wait for `run` before posting the work - you can post it first and then, as soon as `run` will be called, the work will be executed.

Comment: Yes, this is not what I asked in my question. Your answer is opposit of what I asked. :)
*I see a problem with this approach, as if you call run before posting any work, the call will immediately return.*  Not true. `_work = boost::in_place(boost::ref(_ios));` takes care of that.